# How can I get the parent element property before I save and published the children element in Silverstripe Elemental?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am having a little problem using silverstripe elemental. I am trying to get some parent element property in a children element, but only after I save and published the children element, the parent element property becomes available.

For example, I want to get the QuizQuestion element property `QuestionNumber = 2` in children element QuizAnswer, but I only get a default value `QuestionNumber = 0` in the database.

When I `Debug::show($this->QuizQuestion()->QuestionNumber)`, I can see it is indeed 2. How can I get the parent element property before I save and published the children element?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know now this module but normally you should be able to get the parent id out of the current url. It's very hacky but should work for you.

```
public function ItemByUrl() {
  $uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $i = array_search('IDENTIFIER', $uri);

  if(isset($uri[$i+PARTS])) {
    $itemID = $uri[$i+PARTS];
    $item = DATAOBJECTCLASS::get()->byID($itemID);
    if($item) {
      return $item;
    }
  }
}
```

So if your URL is something like that

`admin/.../EditForm/field/ParentDataObject/item/67/ItemEditForm/field/ChildDataObject/item/new`

And you want to get the ParentID 67

IDENTIFIER would be "ParentDataObject"

PARTS would be "2"

and DATAOBJECTCLASS would be "ChildDataObject"

Comment: This could be a workaround though it's hacky as you said. Would love to see other way to achieve it, especially that there are some other properties of the parent dataobject that cannot be got by the URL. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 1):

The parent record should be available at this time. Make sure you call the parent method first.

Under the hood, elemental simply uses GridField so you can search for any GridField related documentation to understand this better.

```
public function onBeforeWrite()
{
    parent::onBeforeWrite();

    // $this->List(); // Obj(ID = 2);
}
```